# How can i know that for how many days i am banned

Tags: support

When i want to suggest some edits. This only gives me a message

> You are temporarily banned from suggesting edits

I know that why i am banned! But now i want do everything on a right way. 
So am i banned for lifetime?? If not then how can i know that after how many days i can start suggesting edit??

Any help will be appreciated from community members.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are banned for 4 more days. You are banned because most probable you weren't paying attention and approved wrong edits.

Comment: Thanks @Marius.

Comment: Is there is any way for user to know that??

Comment: Usually you should get a message below "You are temporarily banned from suggesting edits" saying "Come back in....days ... hours....". but I don't know why you don't have that.

Comment: oh! thanks.. may b this is a bug

Comment: @Marius can you tell what is ban is duration for second and third time?

Comment: I don't know. Do you plan to get there? :)